# Getting two warnings with my useEffect function reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have seen there are similar questions like this post but cannot find one where a function is being called inside the useEffect so please don't mark as duplicate.

So the first warning I get is when the page is loaded...

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

The second is that I am missing a dependency.

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getAllAccounts'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

I use the function getAllAccounts again inside this component which is why I dont place it inside the useEffect.

My cleanup worked before I moved the getAllAccounts and getBeneficiaries outside the useEffect.

Both getAllAccounts and getBeneficiaries are api calls. I am happy to post the code of those if it helps but not sure that would resolve my issue?

useEffect code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    if(mounted){
      getAllAccounts("load");
      getBeneficiaries();
    }
    return function cleanup() {
      mounted = false;
    };
  }, []);
```

p.s if it makes any difference both functions being called are async

Comment: Just for reference the "dependency array" is the second parameter of `useEffect`, and is currently `[]` in your example. The functions don't have to be inside the effect, just referenced in the dependencies.

Comment: @DBS I then get another error - The 'getAllAccounts' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 171) change on every render. To fix this, wrap the definition of 'getAllAccounts' in its own useCallback() Hook - I am not familiar with useCallback so how would I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question in the end.

Changed useEffect to this (based on comments above)

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    if(mounted){
      getAllAccounts("load");
      getBeneficiaries();
    }
    return function cleanup() {
      mountedRef.current = false
      mounted = false;
    };
  }, [getAllAccounts]);
```

Then had to change my async function to a useCallback to prevent the leak happening.

Answer (score 0):

What you said is no reason why you should not add getAllAccounts to the dependency array (that empty array as the second parameter of the useEffect), that should work.

It is unclear what can cause the first warning with the details provided.